# How to show a function is a good kernel?

Tags: real-analysis

A good kernel $K_{\delta}(y)$ must satisfy 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}K_\delta(y)dy=1$$
For each $\eta>0$, 
$$\int_{|y|>\eta}K_\delta(y)dy\to0\text{    as  }\delta\to 0$$
If $K_{\delta}(y)=\delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\pi y^2}{\delta}}$, how to show that this function satisfy the second property? I'm stuck.

Comment: Make the substitution $y = x\sqrt{\delta}$.

Comment: I know how to show the first property, but this substitution also woks for second statement?

Comment: The integrand becomes $e^{-\pi x^2}$. What region is it integrated over?

Comment: The region of integration is $|y|>\eta$.

Comment: After the substitution, you want to describe that in terms of $x$. What does $\lvert y\rvert > \eta$ become after substituting $y = x\sqrt{\delta}$?